# How to make star rating using angular 7 material icon button?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

**SCENARIO:**
I have created a **ratings option** using material **icon-button** as follow:

[image: Rating]

**Expected Result:**

- I want to change the **color** of `icon-button` up to how much user going to select like this:

[image]

- I need to take value like 3,3.5,4 depending on the users selection.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v337tr?file=app/button-types-example.html)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have implemented Amazon like rating system (the same requirement as yours) in my Angular 7 application.  I have used this [sample](https://github.com/ERS-HCL/star-rating-angular-material).  This looks simple, less lines of code and you can reuse the widget.

Demo Url: https://angular-material-star-rating.stackblitz.io

Comment: please give the full stackblitz.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, upvoted your answer, it really saved lot of time.

Comment: Full Url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-star-rating

Comment: Great demo @Jonathan002